# MVC - load data into a modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to click on an item in the main page, pass in an ID, then load data in a modal based on that ID

I have the following code in the cshtml page where the click happens

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: "/Home/GetImageFromLogId?LogId=" + this.specialId,
    success: function (data) {
        $("#modal-content").html(data);
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('error!');
    }
})
```

I then have this in the homecontroller

> ```
>     [HttpPost]
>     public ActionResult GetImageFromLogId(long LogId)
>     {
>         var requestedImageData = processIt.LoadGraphImageData(LogId);
>
>         return PartialView(requestedImageData);
>     }
> ```

processIt.LoadGraphImageData simply return an object with a date, image location, and some Id's

I would like to show this information in the modal, but I'm obviously missing something

I'm relatively new to MVC so struggling to figure out the missing parts

Comment: where and how are you calling the Java Script code which fires the ajax ? What would be `this` there ?

Comment: Have you debugged this at all? Where is it failing? Does `requestedImageData` contain valid view markup when you set a breakpoint?

Comment: check your devtools->network tab and see whether you are getting a 200OK response for your ajax call. If not,check the `response` tab.

Comment: you should return your partial view result with the partial view name like this -> return PartialView("YourPartialViewName",requestedImageData);

Comment: It’s failing on return to the Ajax call and is hitting the alert error, the issue is what I’m returning isn’t html, just an object, I assume I need to write html somewhere ?

Comment: I was missing the cshtml page, i've now created this and it works, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add the cshtml file and then add this

```
return PartialView("~/Views/Home/CameraImage.cshtml");
```